# Sequelize UUID with mySQL: Unable to set default value

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I've been trying for awhile to set id (primary key) for my Users table as UUID. However, I keep getting this error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value, when I attempt to seed it.

This is what I have so far in my Users model:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Users extends Model {};
  
Users.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    user_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notNull: {
          msg: 'Please add a name',
        },
      },
    },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Users',
  });
  return Users;
```

Likewise, this is what I have in my Users migration file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Admins', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      user_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

I'm pretty new to Sequelize, so would love some guidance on what's gone wrong!

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I realised the issue:

For some reason, seeding it by using a seeder file would not auto-generate the fields that I thought would be auto-generated, so I had to put them in manually.

```
'use strict';

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
     await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
       id: uuidv4(),
        user_name: 'John Doe',
        "createdAt": new Date(),
        "updatedAt": new Date()
        }], {});
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

    await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});

  }
};
```

Initially, I had been trying to seed (running the command `npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all`) without the `id: uuidv4()` and the `new Date()`, which was why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),` to your createdAt and updatedAt in your migration file defaults the value to the current timestamp.

```
createdAt: {
   allowNull: false,
   type: Sequelize.DATE,
   defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a very late response but there is an alternative solution for this case.

As stated in [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13224) GitHub issue, which worked for me as well, if you apply following to your defaultValue, it should work:

```
defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('gen_random_uuid()')
```

If I get it right, using Sequelize.UUIDV4 or DataTypes.UUIDV4 does not seem working in migration files but model files.